# Excel macro to create new sheet only with next 14 days

Tags: excel, vba

So I have an excel, which has a dates field and flags.
I need to create a new sheet but only with **date = today() + 14** **AND** where any of the **flags(columns) does not have a "TRUE" string**.

I know how to create a new sheet.
But I'm struggling to create a filter with next 14 days.

I recorded a macro for the next 7 days and it gave me this code, but I haven't been able to modify it for 14, 28 etc.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$959").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        xlFilterNextWeek, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
```

Comment: `xlFilterNextWeek` resolves to 6, so if you want next week, just replace it by the numerical value, `12` or do `2*xlFilterNextWeek`

Comment: I tried the below, but it didn't work: ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$959").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        14, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

Comment: Multiplying by 2 worked, but to get to 14 days I tried adding 2 and it didn't seem to like that : ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$959").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        (2 * xlFilterNextWeek) + 2, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a built-in date filter. You can build your own like this

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$959").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    "<" & Date + 14, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Note that VBA is very US-centric when it comes to dates. If your using this in a country with a non-US date format, you might have to change the Criteria to

```
Critieria1: = "<" & Format$(Date + 14, "yyyy/m/d")
```

or whatever date format works for you. But I would try it without the `Format()` first and only use that if you get odd results.

Comment: The dates are actually US-centric, I reformatted the column to "mm/dd/yy" just to be sure & used the below code, but it doesn't seem to be working :  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$959").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    "<" & Format$(Date + 14, "mm/dd/yy"), Operator:=xlAnd

Comment: Clear any filters, turn on the macro recorder, then filter using Date Filters - Custom Filters - is before or equal to - and type in a date that is 14 days ago. Then turn off the macro recorder and see what it produces. Compare that to your code.